Error when deploying Azure function-app - No route registered for '/DaaS/api/connectionstringvalidation/validate/'
All of a sudden when deploying code to my Azure Functions, it has started complaining about the following:

No route registered for
'/DaaS/api/connectionstringvalidation/validate/'

Any ideas?
I've not seen this before, not done anything actively with any DaaS in the past/present.

Upgrading the pipeline task to AzureFunctionApp@2 seems to have done the trick.
Frustrating with the bad error messages.
